# 2048 Game Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, game

I created a 2048 game clone in Java. However, I am only writing the fundamental algorithm for the game such as the movement, the losing condition, and the algorithm to generate a new tile. This algorithm should be generic enough to work not only on 4 x 4 grid, but also on any size of square grid.

Any review / feedback would be greatly appreciated!

**Tile Class**

```
/**
 * Class of individual tile unit in 2048 game. Value of zero implies an empty tile.
 * 
 * @author dkurniawan
 */
public class Tile {

    private int value;

    /**
     * Instantiate tile with a value of zero (empty). 
     */
    public Tile(){
        this(0);
    }

    /**
     * Instantiate tile with a specific value.
     * 
     * @param value
     */
    public Tile(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }


    public void setValue(int value){    
        this.value = value; 
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    /**
     * Two tiles are the same if they have the same value. (Useful for merging tile)
     * 
     * @param tile
     * @return true if two tiles are equal, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean equals(Tile tile){
        return tile.getValue() == this.getValue();  
    }

    /**
     * Add the value of this tile by the value of the tile in the parameter.
     * 
     * @param tile
     */
    public void merge(Tile tile){
        this.setValue(value + tile.getValue());
    }

    /**
     * Set the value to zero. In other words, delete / empty the tile.
     * 
     */
    public void clear(){
        this.setValue(0);
    }

    public String toString(){
        return (Integer.toString(this.getValue()));
    }

}
```

**Grid Class (The main algorithm is in this class)**

To swipe the tiles in 2048, the game calls the move method (with Direction enum as a parameter)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 * The main game algorithm. The grid contains n x n tiles. Tiles with a value of zero implies an empty tile. 
 * The algorithm operate by passing value to other grid (without moving the object itself. 
 * 
 * @author dkurniawan
 *
 */
public class Grid {


    //size of the grid
    private static final int SIZE = 4;

    private Tile[][] tiles = new Tile[SIZE][SIZE];

    /**
     * Instantiate n x n grid with all zero values (grid with empty tile).
     */
    public Grid(){

        for (int i = 0; i < tiles[0].length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < tiles.length; j++){
                tiles[i][j] = new Tile();
            }

        }
    }

    /**
     * Generate a tile with a random value of 2 or 4 in a random position. 
     * 
     * @return true if successfully placed a new tile, false if there is no empty tile left.
     * 
     */
    public boolean generateNewTile(){

        if (!(hasEmptyTile())){
            return false;
        }

        Random random = new Random();

        //iterate until an empty tile if found
        while (true){

            int x = random.nextInt(SIZE);
            int y = random.nextInt(SIZE);

            if (tiles[x][y].getValue() == 0){

                tiles[x][y].setValue(getNewTileValue());
                return true;

            }

        }

    }

    //get tile value of either 2 or 4   
    private int getNewTileValue(){

        Random random = new Random();

        int rng = random.nextInt(2) + 1;

        return (rng * 2);

    }

    /**
     * 2048 movement algorithm. The main idea of the algorithm is to create a group / set of tile according to the direction chosen.
     * For example, if the user want to move the tile to the right, then the group will be the rows of tile. As a result,
     * each row will have the same movement algorithm. These rows will be sent to a general method.
     *  
     * @param direction Determine which direction the player want to slide the tile.
     */
    public void move(Direction direction){

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){

            //group of tile
            List<Tile> tileSet = new ArrayList<Tile>();

            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){

                switch(direction){

                case LEFT: tileSet.add(tiles[i][j]); break;
                case RIGHT: tileSet.add(tiles[i][SIZE - j - 1]); break;
                case UP: tileSet.add(tiles[j][i]); break;
                case DOWN: tileSet.add(tiles[SIZE - j - 1][i]); break;
                default: break;

                }

            }

            if (!(isEmptyTile(tileSet))){
                slide(tileSet); //main tile group algorithm
            }


        }

    }

    private boolean isEmptyTile(List<Tile> tileSet) {

        for (Tile tile: tileSet){

            if (tile.getValue() != 0){
                return false;
            }

        }

        return true;

    }

    //main tile group algorithm
    private void slide(List<Tile> tileSet){

        slideToEdge(tileSet);
        mergeTile(tileSet);

    }

    //slide all tile into the edge, in case there is a zero in between
    private void slideToEdge(List<Tile> tileSet){

        for (int i = 0; i < tileSet.size(); i++){

            if (remainingIsZero(tileSet, i)){
                return;
            }

            while (tileSet.get(i).getValue() == 0){

                slideTo(tileSet, i);

            }

        }

    }

    private boolean remainingIsZero(List<Tile> tileSet, int i) {

        List<Tile> remainingTile = new ArrayList<Tile>();

        for (int j = i; j < tileSet.size(); j++){
            remainingTile.add(tileSet.get(j));
        }

        return (isEmptyTile(remainingTile));

    }

    private void slideTo(List<Tile> tileSet, int index){

        for (int j = index; j < tileSet.size() - 1; j++){

            tileSet.get(j).setValue(tileSet.get(j + 1).getValue());

        }

        tileSet.get(tileSet.size() - 1).clear();

    }

    //Merge tile, if tile in the direction has the same value.
    private void mergeTile(List<Tile> tileSet){

        for (int i = 0; i < tileSet.size() - 1; i++){

            if (tileSet.get(i).equals(tileSet.get(i + 1))){
                tileSet.get(i).merge(tileSet.get(i + 1));
                tileSet.get(i + 1).clear();
                slideTo(tileSet, i + 1);

            }

        }

    }

    /**
     * Check for losing condition. Losing implies no possible move can be made to change the tile.
     * 
     * @return true, if no possible move left
     */
    public boolean noPossibleMove(){    

        if (hasEmptyTile()){
            return false;
        }

        return !(hasEqualNeighbour());

    }

    private boolean hasEmptyTile(){

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){

                if (tiles[i][j].getValue() == 0){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;

    }

    private boolean hasEqualNeighbour() {

        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){

                //check the tile in the right of the chosen tile. Ignore last column.
                if (j < SIZE - 1){

                    if (tiles[i][j].equals(tiles[i][j + 1])){
                        return true;
                    }

                }

                //check the tile below the chosen tile. Ignore last row.
                if (i < SIZE - 1){

                    if (tiles[i][j].equals(tiles[i + 1][j])){
                        return true;
                    }

                }



            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public String toString(){

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (Tile[] tileRow: tiles){
            for (Tile tile: tileRow){
                sb.append(tile);
                sb.append(" ");
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }

        return sb.toString();

    }

}
```

**Direction Enum**

```
public enum Direction {

    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;

}
```

Comment: It's filled with a bit too many useless comments: you should only use comments that convey extra information / clarify a hard-to-follow code, not stuff like "sets x to y". There are a number of inefficiences, the most notable of which in the generateNewTile method. Your infinite loop may indeed never terminate in a reasonable time for a big number of tiles (say 100 x 100). You are better off having a set of the empty tiles and picking from it at random. Finally, on an aesthetic note, you don't really need double spacing between lines

Comment: The `Tile` class doesn't seem to be doing enough to justify its existence.  Since tiles are basically just numbers, you might be better off just to store a number.  OTOH, if you want to display a graphical result, a `Tile` class that handles the screen representation (graphics) would be pretty reasonable.

Comment: Meanwhile, your `Tiles` field probably actually could be a separate class.  Give it a private array like you have already, and methods for `slideUp()`, `slideLeft()`, etc. and `clear()` and a few other requirements and you'd have a useful class.

Answer (score 4):

Did you test this method:

```
public boolean equals(Tile tile) {
    return tile.getValue() == this.getValue();  
}
```

Especially, did you test it by passing in the `null` value? See "Effective Java" by Joshua Bloch, an awesome book. You could find something like: http://www.ideyatech.com/2011/04/effective-java-equals-and-hashcode/

Your equals method should look something more like:

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {  
    if (this == other) return true;  
    if (!(other instanceof Tile )) return false;  
    final User that = (Tile) other;  
    return this.getUsername().equals(that.getUsername());  
}
```

Then, it seems like this method will block your app and run forever if all tiles are already filled:

```
public boolean generateNewTile()
```

Make sure you have some escape strategy for it.